# Rank of binary matrix related to the number of positive squarefree integers less than $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, matrices, square-free

I posted this question at the Mathematics SE, but received no response there so I am posting it here.

The following fact is stated in the comments-section of sequence [A013928](http://oeis.org/A013928) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

Let $C$ be the $n$-by-$n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-entry is one if $\gcd(i,j)=1$ and zero otherwise.

It is claimed that $\text{rank}(C) = Q(n+1)$, where $Q(n)$ denotes the number of squarefree integers less than $n$.

Looking for a reference on this claim (proving the claim is not an issue) and whether this matrix has been studied previously.

Comment: Have you looked at the links and references for that sequence?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I did. That claim and matrix do not appear in any of the references.

Comment: I don't know if this matrix appears in the literature, although it is likely that it does. Clements and Lindstroem have a slightly different binary matrix with large determinant. It is possible that there is an article which references both matrices, in which case start with a citation search on the Clements and Lindstroem article.  Gerhard "Use High Rank For Low" Paseman, 2018.07.05.

Comment: The fact $rank(C)=Q(n+1)$ can be easily proved, just notice that $gcd(x,p_{1}^{k_1}p_{2}^{k_2}...p_{n}^{k_n})=1 \Leftrightarrow gcd(x,p_{1}p_{2}...p_{n})=1$, and the squarefree columns of the matrix form a basis.